# How to iterate over all child in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

If many models in `Django` have foreign key relationship to a common model then how will it be possible to iterate over all the child models one by one.

I know about `parent.child_set.all()`, but I want to know if there is something that can be helpful to access child using a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to know if there is something that can be helpful to access child using a variable"?.  Do you want to get a single child out of `all` children? – thanks.

Comment: I want to access all children using variables where variable is the name of child model. And if it is not possible with variables then what will be the best way to do so?

Comment: lets put it simply, do you want to access all children using child model class?

May you also include your models into the question above?

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell what you're trying to do....but a simple getattr might help

```
child_var = 'child1'
qs = getattr(ParentModelInstance, child_var+'_set').all()
```